# Is rid=2 significant in PostGIS raster structure?

Tags: postgis, raster

It seems that in most, if not all, examples with raster appear to include the `WHERE rid=2` statement in the query.

http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Value.html

Is there something about the rast structure that requires this, or is this just an artifact of previous examples used to reduce the sample dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. `rid = 2` is purely an artifact of the example datasets used for the documentation.